# Can we run Quartus II on Ubuntu?

Tags: fpga, software, linux, intel-fpga, quartus-ii

I can compile digital components and download them to the boards DE2 and DE2-115 I got. I do it from Windows 7 but I want to enable this on ubuntu while the files from Altera are for Red Hat Linux. I've seen in the [Altera forum](http://www.alteraforum.com/forum/showthread.php?t=37072) that there're success installing it on 64-bit Ubuntu which I want to try. Should I try or wait for an official version? Will there be an official version for Ubuntu and not only Red Hat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've successfully installed Quartus II on Ubuntu. I followed mainly those instructions:

http://www.philpem.me.uk/elec/fpga/quartus-ubuntu/

IIRC I had to modify somethings, I think it was the udev-Rules and the symlink from /bin/sh (defaults to /bin/dash in Ubuntu/Debian but Quartus II expects it to be /bin/bash).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to wait, you can do this without any major problem, you may have to add some extra libraries for the JTAG debugger or the USB driver, but the main parts of Quartus works very well under Ubuntu.